# How to find specific substrings in Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, filter, substring

I am working on an Excel spreadsheet that contains a column with product descriptions. Some descriptions have the word "that" attached to the word that follows or precedes it, in the description. i.e. "thatensures", "thathave", "thatwill","knowthat", etc.

Is there any sort of filter I could use or create to help me find all of these sort of words in the specific column of descriptions? Thanks!

Comment: [AutoFilter](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Quick-start-Filter-data-by-using-an-AutoFilter-08647E19-11D1-42F6-B376-27B932E186E0) with contains "that"

Comment: Scott's is the simplest answer.  Another thought is to use the `=find()` function to find all of the strings with "that" in it, but it's not clear based on your question if you want to do anything after you find the list.

Comment: I think you'll need to use regexp (or a series of If Then) if the task is specifically "find words beginning or ending in 'that' "

Comment: Edit: Once I have identified all of the cells that contain such a word, I'd like to make the fix manually. The concern is to find all the cells that contain such a word.

Furthermore, autofiltering "that", won't work because it will give me every cell which contains the word "that", and that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @leo - to be clear, I did not suggest to AutoFilter on the word "that", but to use the Feature in `AutoFilter` for `contains` "that", as opposed to `equals` "that". This will work, but will also returns instances where cells equal "that" entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If your example data set was

> thathave
>
> thatwill
>
> have
>
> knowthat

then you could use `=IFERROR(SEARCH("that",<cell#>,1),0)` which will return 0 if "that" is not found and a positive integer of the location "that" begins if it is found. In this example, the function will return

> 1
>
> 1
>
> 0
>
> 5

Note that this will detect cases where "that" is a standalone word i.e. preceded by a space. You can then sort or filter depending on whether the value is 0 or >=1.

**EDIT**

For cases where "that" is a standalone string, use the same `=IFERROR(SEARCH(" that",<cell#>,1),0)` but with a space preceding the search string. You can then compare strings with "that" present (a positive number) and filter by whether or not it is a standalone (also a positive number)

For example,

> thathave
>
> thatwill
>
> have
>
> knowthat
>
> know that

yields

> 1 | 0
>
> 1 | 0
>
> 0 | 0
>
> 5 | 0
>
> 2 | 1

If both numbers in each row are >=1, then you can omit those cases

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following list in `A1:A7`

```
thatensures
thatwill
thathave
knowthat
that
mouse
knowthat
```

place this formula in B1 `=IF(A1="that",A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND("that",A1)),A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"that","")))` and drag down.

Results will be:

```
ensures
will
have
know
that
mouse
know
```

Comment: `=IF(AND(LOWER(A1)<>"that",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("that",A1)),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" that",A1))),NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("that ",A1)))),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"that",""),A1)`  I think the OP whants to keep `that stays` or `this that stays` or `And this that`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I feel like I answered this too early, because it's not totally clear what the OP *exactly* wants. Sometimes I end up doing that and it helps .. other times ...

Comment: It's like firing a bow and arrow blindfolded on a turn table some times